# Run Loop on the sheets other than mentioned vba

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am new here and trying to learn things by looking at experts and need your help to get my code corrected. I tried looking at old data but not able to get any info.

I have created a vba code using loop - For / next code which is working fine when i use only one sheet name which doesn't need to get summarized like below:

```
For Each w In Worksheets
If w.Name <> "Summary" Then

With w
'My code
End With

Next
```

but when i am trying to use array with sheet names which is not required to summarize. I am getting error when i am writing the code using array itself, it looks very silly but i almost spend 8 days to find out what i am doing wrong, would be great help if any of your correct me with this:

Code used

```
For Each w In Worksheets

If w.Name <> Array("Summary", "Not Certified", "STAT Reconciliations", "Blank Account#", "Blank Description", "Blank Line#", "Blank Reference", "Prepd Rec's-Unidentified Bal>1", "Preparere Unassigned", "Approver Unassigned", "Reviewer Unassigned", "Acct Reviewer Unassigned", "Acct Owner Unassigned", "Key should be Non-Key", "Non-Key should be Key", "Blank Risk Rating", "Timelines", "Recon WorkFlow") Then

With w

My code
End With
Next
```

Would be helpful if anyone can fix this!

Thanks a lot and have a great weekend for all of you

Comment: see:  http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1114511-run-loop-on-the-sheets-other-than-mentioned.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if sh is in the array

```
    Sub LookSheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim NotSH(0 To 15) As String
    Dim F As Boolean

    'Array of Sheet Names you don't want to use
    NotSH(0) = "Summary"
    NotSH(1) = "Not Certified"
    NotSH(2) = "STAT Reconciliations"
    NotSH(3) = "Blank Account#"
    NotSH(4) = "Blank Description"
    NotSH(5) = "Blank Line#"
    NotSH(6) = "Blank Reference"
    NotSH(7) = "Prepd Rec's-Unidentified Bal>1"
    NotSH(8) = "Preparere Unassigned"
    NotSH(9) = "Reviewer Unassigned"
    NotSH(10) = "Acct Owner Unassigned"
    NotSH(11) = "Key should be Non-Key"
    NotSH(12) = "Non-Key should be Key"
    NotSH(13) = "Blank Risk Rating"
    NotSH(14) = "Timelines"
    NotSH(15) = "Recon WorkFlow"


    For Each sh In Sheets   'loop through sheets
        F = False
        For Each Arr In NotSH   'NotSH=sh.name?
            If sh.Name = Arr Then    'If it is, set F =true
                F = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Arr
        If F = False Then    'if not found then do something in the sheet
            MsgBox sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```